# I am not able to delete single text messages in a conversation since updating to iOS 8

Tags: ios

Before iOS 8 I could click on a text, get the `More` option and see a trash can on the bottom of the screen. This would allow me to delete a single text from a conversation.

Now there is only a camera in the place the trash can used to be. I have reset my phone and the trash can comes back, but only briefly. Today I totally erased my phone and the ability to delete single text messages from a conversation still does not last more than a few texts.

Is there a way to make this feature persist?

Comment: I have the same problem. If you turn off the phone the trash can appears and you can delete maybe one message. After that, the camera replaces the trash can again.

Answer (score 1):

If you double-tap on a message rather than single-tap, up pops a "Copy/More..." selector, and hitting "More..." gives you the trash and forwarding arrow icons (along with the ability to select other messages to delete at the same time.)

If the icons do not apear, or if they stop apearing, there is something not working the way it does for me. Some people find that the icons re-appear after a restart (if only for a short time). Perhaps completely "quitting" the application would help? If you double-click on the home button, and then "upswipe" the Messages window does that have any effect when Messages is re-started?

Comment: When I double tap on a message I do get the copy/more icon. When I choose "more" I am able to select that message or additional texts but I don't have the trash can. There is still just the camera below left.

Comment: After the double-tap/More... action, does the bottom right of the screen display the "forward" cruvy arrow?     usr95625 suggests that powering down the phone and restarting it made it work properly for a while, but the problem quickly returned. Does a shutoff/turn-on cycle help at all in your situation?

Comment: Yes, it works for a short time and then my trash can and forward arrow disappear. I even did "Erase All Content & Settings" to see if that would be a fix and it did not fix it.

Comment: If the icons do not apear, or if they stop apearing, there is something not working the way it does for me. Some people find that the icons re-appear after a restart (if only for a short time). Perhaps completely "quitting" the application would help? If you double-click on the home button, and then "upswipe" the Messages window does that have any effect when Messages is re-started?